# load test of a 3D audio system with the web audio api

Tags: audio, cpu, load-testing, web-audio-api, noise

Hello I have a self implemented web conference room with a 3D audio system. I am testing how many users can join this web conference room and use the 3D audio system,

To each new user the audio stream is instantiated as a new audio source and a panner node. That means if there are 20 users in the web conference room, then there are 20 audio sources and 20 panner nodes connected to one audiocontext.

When I get to 13 users, then it starts to buzz. I'm not sure if it's the CPU, since the CPU is at 92% utilization. I think it could be something else, but I don't know what. Is it the framework itself ?

by the way, if I use a more powerful computer, then more then 13 users can connect before the audio system starts to buzz.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Chrome extension developed by the Web Audio team at Google called [Audion](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/audion/cmhomipkklckpomafalojobppmmidlgl). It allows you to visualize the audio graph. Maybe that already helps to reveal unused nodes or anything else that looks suspicious.

If that doesn't help you could also try to profile your code in Chrome as described [here](https://web.dev/profiling-web-audio-apps-in-chrome/).

Similar things can also be done in Firefox as described [here](https://blog.paul.cx/post/profiling-firefox-media-workloads/) and [here](https://blog.paul.cx/post/profiling-firefox-real-time-media-workloads/).

Unfortunately there is currently no way to do any of this at runtime. But there might be an API soon to access the current render capacity. You could for example use this to change the `panningModel` from `'HRTF'` to `'equalpower'` if the browser struggles with the current workload.